# AWS IOT with DynamoDB logging service issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, iot

We have implemented a simple DynamoDB database that is updated by a remote IoT device that does not have a user (i.e. root) constantly logged in to the device. We have experience issues in logging data as the database is not updated if a user (i.e. root) is not logged into the device (we log in via a ssh session). We are confident that the process is running in the background as we are using a Linux service that runs on bootup to execute a script. We have verified that the script runs on bootup and successfully pushes data to Dynamo upon user log in (via ssh). We have also tried to disassociate a screen session to allow for the device to publish data to Dynamo but this did not seem to fix the issue. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Does amazon AWS require a user (i.e. root) to be logged in to the device at all times in order to allow for data to be published to AWS?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. I have done similar setup and it is working fine. Are you sure that your IoT device does not go into some kind of sleep mode after a while ?

Comment: It may; it definitely does not when we leave an ssh session up and running. We are using an Intel Edison. We've tried trouble shooting this issue but have kind of hit a wall - we're pretty new to AWS and programming at this level. We know our device pushes data as expected when we're logged on, but as soon as our session is terminated, it stops. We think the service is still running but nothing shows on the data base. Do you have any suggestions? We're using python SDK on AWS IoT with DyanamoDB. Thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: Do you have any kind of module on your IoT device that can give a hint whether the system is live or not ? For example, if you use Intel Edison for Ardunio module, you can easily connect some LED light to any port. Then, modify your program to let the light blink, which gives you an indication that the session is alive or not. 

Or if can share some code here, we can look into it.